# Typescript file change does not recognized by Visual Studio build and thinks all up to date

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, msbuild, tsc, tsconfig

I am using TypeScript in ASP.NET Core 3 (preview 5) project, with the latest VS 2019 16.1.1 (tsc: 3.4)

All my TypeScript files are compile fine when I use "Rebuild All" or touch any C# files, or touch tsconfig.json.

However when I modify any of my .ts files, save then "Build" VS 2019 says all up to date, and does nothing.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I changed the order of `compileOnSave` and `compilerOptions`, it does not matter
- I tried to set `compileOnSave` `true` or `false` it does not help. Btw `compileOnSave` `true` does nothing, I do not care, to much (I am not insatiable, it would be enough for me to compile on build :-), but may have diagnostic value.

**tsconfig.json:**

```
"compileOnSave": false, // does not matter if true or false
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "none",
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noEmitOnError": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "target": "es2015",
  "lib": [
    "es2015",
    "es5",
    "dom"
  ],
  "outDir": "wwwroot/js/gen-ts",
  "typeRoots": [
    "./wwwroot/lib/@types"
  ]
},
"include": [
  "./Scripts"
]
```

Comment: 1.What's the result if you create a new project with similar configuration? 2.And have you checked if the build action of your .ts files are "TypeScriptCompile"? 3.Also, you can try setting the build action of tsconfig.json to "None", then the msbuild properties would control its behavior. I've had same environment like yours(.net core3.0 preview5, typescript3.4), but it works normally in my side.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: Thx for suggestions: 1) With brand new project it is the very same. 2) If I set TypeScriptCompile, (originally it was none), then build compiles unconditionally the whole project, regardless if there were any change. 3) If I set None for tsconfig.json (originally it was the default: Content) then my project does not build with many typescript errors (which is understandable, some setting are mandatory. Omitting tsconfig.json is not an option)

Comment: Hi friend, as you mentioned `the very same with brand new project`, could you share the solution by one-drive or github so that I can check it directly. I got the same developer env like yours but the changes are recognized by vs. So maybe I need to check if this issue result from vs settings or project settings itself.

Comment: Here we are, please see the diagnostic comments in the .csproj file. https://github.com/g-pickardou/TypeScriptBuildDiagnostics

Answer (score 2):

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Find yourprojectname.csproj file
3. Open yourprojectname.csproj any text editor
4. Change Node `<None Include="tsconfig.json" /> TO <Content Include="tsconfig.json" />`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your project. I reproduced similar issue on my side.

Here are the suggestions which may help:

1.Move your .ts files from Common folder to Scripts folder since content of your tsconfig.json is:

```
"include": [
  "./Scripts"
```

2.Go=>Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>.net core=>Up-To-Date Checks=>> make sure we've checked the `Don't call msbuild if a project appears to be up-to-date`.

3.Delete the bin and obj folder and rebuild the solution.

(Not sure which steps above really help, though in some aspects I've resolved the issue, I can't figure out what really works since I've done too many changes and tests)

4.After that, the build output will display `successful build` most of the time though we don't make changes.

But i think it just displays Successful build message(It actually doesn't build those files):

1.If I change xx.ts, only xx.js will be regenerated.(You can compare the modified time of the .js files)

2.If I do some change in xx.cs file, only the .dll and some files will be regenerated but not the xx.js file.

I think now the build behavior is actually mostly normal except its wrong build output which may mislead us. For this aspect, you can report this issue by Help menu=>Send Feedback=>Report a problem to report it.

Hope I didn't misunderstood something:( Please feel free to correct me if something is wrong in my answer.

Comment: I did all, still  not working here. Btw: Common folder is *under* the Scripts, but I moved as you said, "Don't call msbuild" was already checked. If the MsBuild packages is in the csproj, the after modding a ts file it rebuilds endlessly for ctrl+b. If the package is commented out, then ignores the .ts file change.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But for now I can't reproduce same issue on my side even with the project you shared. Have you tried tto repair vs or go Tools=>Import and Export Settings to reset vs settings?